# If regular price is blank show only sales price in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

Just like the title said:

How can i show only the sales price in Woocommerce if the regular price is blank?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something like:

```
$regular_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
$price_sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
if ($regular_price == '') {
    echo $price_sale;
} else {
    echo $regular_price;
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning this belongs in a price filter / hook.

Comment: Thanks, but in which price filter does it belong?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html',  'change_product_price_html', 10, 2 );

function change_product_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
  global $post;
  $id = !empty( $product->get_id() ) ? $product->get_id() : $post->ID;

  $regular_price = get_post_meta( $id, '_regular_price', true);
  $sale_price = get_post_meta( $id, '_sale_price', true);

  $price_html = ( $regular_price == '' ) ? $sale_price : $regular_price;

  return $price_html;
}
```

Please use this code in your active theme's functions.php file .

Comment: @BertvandenEinden can you let us know what exactly is not working here? Also have you tried to enable debug to check errors?